# Can we save image slices in sub folders in Photoshop?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, extract

I am using Photoshop CS5, by default, Photoshop saves image slices in a folder named `images`.

This is fine but there are lots of images, saving them all in a single folder becomes quite messy.

What I would like to do in Photoshop is, it allows me to specify which sub-folder a slice should go under the default `images` folder.

For example, a website template PSD file, I would like to save image slices that appear in the header under `images\header\`. Maybe for the images in the footer, they should go `images\footer\`.

Of course, I can group them manually after the slices are extracted.

If possible, I would like to define them in Photoshop, so that every time the image slices are extracted, they each go to the specified sub-folder automatically.

Is this possible in Photoshop?

Comment: If you want this level of control, it's probably time you moved past using slices in Photoshop :-/